# Jupyter : Arguments in line magic commands

Tags: python, jupyter

I often use the cell magic command of Jupyter

```
%%px --targets 3
#Some code
```

to run some code on cluster number 3. What is the syntax to achieve the same result using a **line** magic command?

I tried

```
%px --targets 3 #Some code
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Many line magics take arguments. Enter `%magic` to see the docs. There could be differences between the line magics and cell magics with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Not tested) You can associate a suffix with your cluster number 3 as described here https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/parallel/magics.html#multiple-active-views

So assuming your `IPython.parallel.Client` instance is called `rc`

```
c3 = rc[3]
c3.activate('_3')
c3.block = True
```

then you will be able to write

```
%px_3 #some code
```

for the line magic and

```
%%px_3 
#some code
```

for the cell magic.